Category of coverings in a Grothendieck topology
Let $(C,\tau)$ be a site, i.e. $C$ is a category and $\tau$ is a set of families $\{U_i\to U\}_{i\in I}$ of morphisms in $C$, which is required to satisfy certain axioms. The elements of $\tau$ are called coverings.
In Introduction to Etale Cohomology by Tamme I read that, given an object $U$ in $C$, there is a category $\mathcal J_U$ where the objects are the coverings of $U$ and where a morphism  $\{U'_j\to U\}_{j\in J}\to\{U_i\to U\}_{i\in I}$ consists of these data: (1) a map $e:J\to I$ and (2) a family of  $U$-morphisms $\{U'_j\to U_{e(j)}\}_{j\in J}$.
The problem is that it seems to me that $\mathcal J_U$ has a terminal object, namely the covering $\{1_U:U\to U\}$; however this wouldn't make sense because later the Cech cohomology is defined via the limit of a diagram indexed by $\mathcal J_U^{op}$. Hence if $\mathcal J_U^{op}$ had an initial object the computation of the limit would be always trivial, and I don't think it's the case. However it really seems to me that defined the morphisms as in (1) and (2), there is one and only one morphism from any covering $\{U_i\to U\}_{i\in I}$ to $\{1_U\}$; the map $e:I\to \{*\}$ is the only possible, and the only possible family of $U$-morphisms is $\{U_i\to U\}_{i\in I}$. What do you think, do you see where is the misunderstanding? Thanks for any clarify

Are you sure that Cech cohomology is described as a limit, and not a colimit? Maybe you missed a switch of direction somewhere because of the contravariance of cohomology, or perhaps you got confused because of the unfortunate conflict of terminology due to which a "direct limit" is actually a colimit?

The Cech cohomology group $H^n(X,F)$ is defined as the colimit of the diagram that maps a covering $\mathcal{U}$ to $H^n(\mathcal{U},F) = H^n ( C^*(\mathcal{U},F))$, and a refinement map $\mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{U}$ to a certain homomorphism $H^n(\mathcal{U},F) \to H^n(\mathcal{V},F)$. Since the index category (the opposite of the category of coverings) is filtered, this is actually a filtered colimit. The index category has an initial object, as you have observed, but that's OK. You just mixed up colimits with limits. Maybe the confusion comes from the (utterly confusing and old-fashioned) term "direct limit".

Thanks in fact I had not realized that the direction of the arrow under the notation $\rm lim$ changes between limit and colimit

Yes, $\varprojlim$ denotes a limit, while $\varinjlim$ denotes a colimit. This is also because, confusingly, limits and colimits are classically known as inverse and direct limits, and the arrow direction indicates this.
